# Bug in HypergeometricPFQRegularized?

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs, warning-messages, special-functions

**Bug persisting through 11.2**

---

I'am facing a trouble with HypergeometricPFQRegularized. Mathematica hangs if imaginary part of one of the arguments has zero imaginary part with decimal point as the following example shows:

```
\[Nu]j = 2 + I*0
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1}, {1 - \[Nu]j, 
  1 + \[Nu]j}, -14.28]
\[Nu]j = 2 + I*0.
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1}, {1 - \[Nu]j, 
  1 + \[Nu]j}, -14.28]

(*
Out[404]= 2

Out[405]= 0.112647

Out[406]= 2. + 0. I

During evaluation of In[404]:= Divide::infy: Infinite expression 3/0 encountered.

During evaluation of In[404]:= Divide::infy: Infinite expression 3/0 encountered.

During evaluation of In[404]:= Divide::infy: Infinite expression 3/0 encountered.

During evaluation of In[404]:= General::stop: Further output of Divide::infy will be suppressed during this calculation.
*)
```

This code is used in heavy serial calculations which hangs sometimes and my investigation indicated on the above trouble with HypergeometricPFQRegularized. Could someone propose simple workaround? I need effective code that would round [Nu]j when it is close to an integer.

Comment: Perhaps `Rationalize` or `Chop` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Diagnosis**

Upon inspecting the source code for `HypergeometricPFQRegularized` with

```
<< GeneralUtilities`
PrintDefinitions[HypergeometricPFQRegularized]
```

I have tracked that error in the OP's example down to a poorly constructed pattern for the 10th `DownValue`:

```
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[a_List,{b1___,Except[_Complex, c_],b2___},z_] := ...
```

Clearly the programmer intended for the rule to be applied in case `c` was real, but it fails to match if `c` is an approximate real number with head `Complex`.

Furthermore, the RHS of the rule, additionally imposes a `Condition`:

```
... := Condition[(*body*), Internal`RealValuedNumericQ[c] && 
                           Block[{rc = Round[c]}, rc <= 0 && c == rc]]
```

which among other things again checks for the real-valuedness of `c`, but failed to pass if `c` has head `Complex`.

**Resolution**

To fix this code, I have taken the liberty of modifying that rule (along with parts of the body) so that it functions as it was (likely) intended.  From a fresh kernel, run the following:

```
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{}, {}, 0]; (*loads definitions*)
Unprotect[HypergeometricPFQRegularized];

(*Modifies the 10th rule*)
DownValues[HypergeometricPFQRegularized] = 
  ReplacePart[DownValues[HypergeometricPFQRegularized], 10 ->
    HoldPattern[HypergeometricPFQRegularized[a_List, {b1___, c_, b2___}, z_] /; PossibleZeroQ[Im[c]]] :> 
      Module[{temp, v},
         temp = Select[{b1, c, b2}, (Last[Internal`TestIntegerQ[#]] && # <= 0) &];
         v = 1 - Round[Min[temp]]; 
         z^v (Times @@ Pochhammer[a, v] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[a + v,
           Append[System`HypergeometricPFQDump`reduce[{b1, c, b2}, {1 - v}] + v, 1 + v], z])
      ] /; Block[{rc = Round[c]}, rc <= 0 && c == rc]];

Protect[HypergeometricPFQRegularized];
```

And now, the numerical evaluation proceeds without problems:

```
νj = 2 + I*0.;
HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1/2, 1}, {1 - νj, 1 + νj}, -14.28]

(*  0.112647  *)
```

Comment: `PrintDefinitions` seems like a really useful function!